# Wordpress facebook share - og:image blank

Tags: wordpress

I tried everything but I can't find the problem.
I got this site http://www.ilsanoquotidiano.com and if I try to share to facebook a news, the og:image is always blank, but up to a month ago this works fine.

I tried with plugins or manually but the og:image is always blank even in facebook debugger but the raw tag is correct.

Could anyone help me?

Thanks

Comment: Your featured images appear properly in the Facebook debugger. I can't replicate the problem. If the information on the Facebook debugger is wrong, please click on the button saying: `Scrape Again`. I tried different posts and they were parsed correctly on Facebook debugger.

Comment: I believe that Facebook employs some caching on shared links. Thus, it may be the case that it has a cached version without an image, and that your current setup its actually correct. The scraping tool suggests that the image is available, so I'd give it a few hours before trying again.

Comment: If in your page or post no image then og:image can' find that image and it will automatically fetch your logo from image section and show in share options.

Also there is multiple option to show your og:image.

Answer (score 0):

You can scrap the facebook sharing information via debugger. Link to check the result is given below:

https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/sharing/?q=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.ilsanoquotidiano.com%2F

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the reply, reading online I found that a problem could be the Jetpack version update, I tried to deactivate the plugin and after few hours everithing worked fine. I can't figure why happened this.